# 'Phalanger' is not a valid short file name

Tags: phalanger

I want to integrate wordpress with .Net. For this i need to install Phalanger

I have got following error while installing Phalanger

" 'Phalanger' is not a valid short file name"

I am stuck with this error.

Comment: what installer do you run?

Comment: Windows default installer

Comment: Also please tell me how to get assemblies hpNetCore.IL.dll, PhpNetCore.dll, PhpNetClassLibrary.dll and PhpNetXmlDom.dll that are required for  "Installation-Free Phalanger web"

Comment: And where did you download the setup package?

Comment: Is it Phalanger 4.0 ? Is it from CodePlex or Visual Studio gallery ? Does it include Tools for VS?

Comment: yes i have downloaded phalanger from http://phalanger.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Please download and use http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/419916fb-ec89-4f18-ba97-75cf66037797 it is the latest Phalanger 4.0 with integration for Visual Studio.